# Most efficient LAD solver

Tags: regression, optimization, algorithms, least-absolute-deviations

What is the most efficient way to solve linear Least absolute deviation regression problem?

I know it can be solved using linear programming, is there a better/faster method?

Edit: I'm interested in the more theoretical aspect, hence by "efficient" I mean that it have some type of upper bound on its run-time.

Comment: If you are going to use a non-linear solver such as Levenberg-Marquardt or Gradient Descent, you will need good initial parameter estimates for the solver. If you can use standard OLS to get the sum-of-squared-error solution, this is usually close to the LAD solution and can be used as initial parameter estimates.

Comment: Is your answer based on rigorous bounds for the running time or  by empirical observations?

Comment: My comment was intended as a potentially helpful suggestion regarding initial parameter estimates only.